# Change HTML and CSS per Matrix row

Tags: matrix

I have a complex html/css structure per 'row' that I would like to use Matrix to populate. Design markup as follows:

```
<!--- feature left -->
<section class="features-inner dark-bg-container">
    <div class="row collapse small-uncollapse" >
        <div class="medium-5 small-12 columns end dark-bg" >
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-5 medium-push-2 small-12 columns end dark-bg-icon" >
            <img src="img/image.svg" class="feature-image"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--- end of feature left -->

<!--- feature right -->
<section class="features-inner gold-bg-container">
    <div class="row collapse small-uncollapse" >
        <div class="medium-5 medium-push-7 small-12 columns gold-bg" >
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-5 medium-pull-5 small-12 columns end gold-bg-icon">
            <img src="img/image.svg" class="feature-image"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</section>
<!--- end of feature right -->
```

How would I get Matrix to change the markup per 'row'? I looked at switch but that seems to be for types of block content/types.

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looping through Matrix rows, you can use [{{ loop.index }} or {{ loop.index0 }}](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) to see which row you're at.

With loop.index, you could create html for each row number, or (for instance) create different html for even/uneven:

```
{% for row in entry.matrixFieldHandle %}
    {% if loop.index is divisible by(2) %}
        <p class="even">{{ row.text }}</p>
    {% else %}
        <p class="uneven">{{ row.text }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Twig has tests for [even](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/even.html) and odd, so `{% if loop.index is even %}` will work too.